# How to fix the problem of pm2 using netmask 1.0.6 causing an high level threat

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I was working on my project and was using `pm2-runtime` command for the runtime environment but the problem coming in my terminal while running the command `npm i` gives 2 level warnings that are

```
  High            netmask npm package vulnerable to octal input data            

  Package         netmask                                                       
  Patched in      >=2.0.1                                                       

  Dependency of   pm2                                                           

  Path            pm2 > @pm2/agent > proxy-agent > pac-proxy-agent >            
                  pac-resolver > netmask                                        

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1658                             


  High            netmask npm package vulnerable to octal input data            

  Package         netmask                                                       

  Patched in      >=2.0.1                                                       

  Dependency of   pm2                                                           

  Path            pm2 > @pm2/io > @pm2/agent-node > proxy-agent >               
                  pac-proxy-agent > pac-resolver > netmask                      

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1658
```

I am using this command in the place of `npm start` can anyone please suggest to me some alternative for the same command

`"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production pm2-runtime start index.js"`

Comment: There is an issue open regarding this: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/5036

Comment: i need an alternative of pm2 to do the same work as pm2 is doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install latest PM2 version:

```
npm install pm2@latest -g
pm2 update
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Yarn also solves this

```
yarn add pm2@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a very similar problem. My issue was that for some reason I was using an outdated version of netmask in the npm that was causing a critical error and preventing ionic from installing. The solution for me was running the command...

```
npm rebuild
```